# python: dictionary and if statements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file to read and a dictionary.
If the file says:

```
sort-by username
```

I want the dictionary to be

```
d = {'sort-by': 'username'}
```

if the file says :

```
sort-by name
```

then I want the dictionary to be

```
d = {'sort-by': 'name'}
```

right now, I have:

```
if 'user' in line:
    d['sort-by'] = 'username'
else:
    d['sort-by'] = 'name'
```

however, even though the file says sort-by username, I keep getting

```
d = {'sort-by': 'name'}
```

why is this?

Comment: please put the full code so we can help you better

Comment: 'If in' is mainly meant for lists, I believe you're doing a string comparison here rather than comparing lists?

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore `x in y` works perfectly well for strings.

Comment: please check to make sure that the variable *line* has the word 'user' in it and that it is in lower case and not 'sort-by Username'.

Comment: Hi, as also @MKoosej suggested, it would be better to add in the question the sample of text on which you are working. Since, in this way there is less ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

```
print dict(map(str.split,open("some_file.txt")))
```

assuming your file actually looks like your example

if you have any control it may be more appropriate to store your data as json